# grep to ignore the first character

Tags: shell, unix, grep

If I have a bunch of lines that have :

```
//mainHtml = "https://
mainHtml = "https:
//https:www.google.com
public String ydmlHtml = "https://remando
aasdfa dsfadsf a asdfasd fasd fsdafsdaf
```

Now I want to grep only those lines which have "https:" in them, but they  should NOT start with "//"

So far I have :

```
cat $javaFile | grep -e '\^\/ *https:*\'
```

where $javaFile is the file I want to look for the words.
My output is a blank. 
Please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use character class to negate the start of lines. We use `-E` option to use ERE or Extended Regular Expression.

```
grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*https' file
```

With your sample data:

```
$ cat file
//mainHtml = "https://
mainHtml = "https:
//https:www.google.com
public String ydmlHtml = "https://remando
aasdfa dsfadsf a asdfasd fasd fsdafsdaf
```

```
$ grep -E '^[^/]{2}.*https' file
mainHtml = "https:
public String ydmlHtml = "https://remando
```

You may also choose to write it without the `-E` option by saying:

```
grep '^[^/][^/].*https' file
```

Comment: You can also use `awk '!/^[/][/].*https/' file`

Answer (score 1):

In two steps:

```
grep -v '^//' | grep 'https:'
```

- `grep -v '^//'` removes the lines starting with `//`
- `grep 'https:'` gets the lines containing `http:`

Comment: What if I want to ignore the lines that start with // and still have https

Comment: Just combine the two using the pipe character: `grep -v '^//' | grep 'https:'`. Otherwise, you can use @jaypal's solution which looks nicer!

Comment: @jaypal sorry budd, dont remember it, but Will check it soon :)